# Does a closed surface in the 3-sphere bound a handlebody?

Tags: geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

If a closed surface is embedded in the 3-sphere, then does it bound a handlebody?

Comment: I understand that every closed and orientable surface is a boundary of genus n handle body where $n \geq 0$.

Answer (score 5):

Not necessarily. Start with a sphere and add a knotted tube on the inside and a knotted tube on the outside. This is a genus two surface that does not bound a handlebody.

Comment: Regarding your example, isn't not boundary of genus 2 handle body?

Comment: I mean knotted genus 2 handle body

Comment: No, because the tubes are to the inside and outside.